# How to change the android emulator AVD emulating ARM5T to emulate ARM5TE

Tags: android, arm, android-virtual-device

My marmalade application is reporting that my AVD is emulating ARM5T and that it is built for ARM5TE. I am unable to find documentation explaining why it defaults to ARM5T and how to change this setting. Does anyone know where I can find documentation on this topic?

Comment: https://devnet.madewithmarmalade.com/questions/7736/android-arm5te-vs-arm5t-error.html

Comment: Its the emulator itself that is emulating ARM5T, is there a way to emulate ARM5TE or could it be the memory corruption in my app that is causing the emulator to emulate ARM5T or seem to at least. What does the emulator emulate when you choose armabi not armv7.